# Pass Parameter to Azure Powershell Function

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions, azure-powershell

I'm new to the Azure environment. I want to execute an .exe file by passing blob storage as an input and output parameter

below is my Json Function and PowerShell code I am not sure how to pass the input blob storage file as parameter and get the output on the blob storage.

I tried to run the below code but i am getting error

Function.json

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "Timer",
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "schedule": "0 */5 * * * *"
    },
    {
      "name": "inputBlob",
      "direction": "in",
      "type": "blob",
      "path": "inputfilepath/{name}",
      "connection": "test23_STORAGE"
    },
    {
      "name": "outputBlob",
      "direction": "out",
      "type": "blob",
      "path": "outputfilepath/{name}",
      "connection": " test23_STORAGE"
    }
  ]
}
```

Run.ps1

```
# Input bindings are passed in via param block.
param($Timer,$inputBlob,$outputBlob)

# Get the current universal time in the default string format.
$currentUTCtime = (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()

# The 'IsPastDue' property is 'true' when the current function invocation is later than scheduled.
if ($Timer.IsPastDue) {
    Write-Host "PowerShell timer is running late!"
}

# Write an information log with the current time.
Write-Host "PowerShell timer trigger function ran! TIME: $currentUTCtime"
Set-Location "C:\home\site\wwwroot\TimerTrigger1"
.\Extractor.exe -F $inputBlob -E $outputBlob
```

Error

```
2022-09-10T07:09:45Z   [Information]   Executing 'Functions.TimerTrigger1' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=07f70ccc-3e39-4e98-a830-73bfda54d101)
2022-09-10T07:09:45Z   [Error]   Executed 'Functions.TimerTrigger1' (Failed, Id=07f70ccc-3e39-4e98-a830-73bfda54d101, Duration=7ms)
```

Comment: Please include the error in your post.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, we cannot use multiple input triggers, but we can use multiple input/output binding of the same trigger in one trigger function.

[image]

> I want to execute an .exe file by passing blob storage as an input and output parameter

This might be done in 2 ways either fetching that `.exe` file from the Storage blob container path and running it or using the WebJobs with CRON Tab expression for these kinds of tasks.

From the Azure Functions, define one function for triggering the `.exe` file at runtime to run and another function for storing the output of that `.exe` application in the blob storage.